# Is it known how much computation a fixed-point combinator gets you?

Tags: universal-computation, combinatory-logic, fixed-points

It is well-known that the [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) are enough to get universal computation, though the original version of combinatory calculus used [BCKW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system). However, it is possible to get a fixed-point combinator from just the B and W combinators (by a construction of Statman: `(B(WW))((BW)((BB)B))` is a fixed-point combinator). Given that fixed-points are used in some instances to compute, I was wondering how much of computation one can get at this point. I would be quite surprised if one could get universal computation, so I ask the more modest question about how much computation we get. Or, to put it another way, what do we lack?

I would be interested in knowing either what we get from just a fixed-point combinator, or else what we get from B and W, taking into account the fact we get a fixed-point combinator from these.

I'm aware of Wolfram's recent [S combinator challenge](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/06/1920-2020-and-a-20000-prize-announcing-the-s-combinator-challenge/) to prove that universal computation can arise from just S, but this is something of a different flavour.

Comment: It is claimed on IRC (Libera Chat, #esolangs) that BCW is Turing-complete, although large amounts of garbage are built up during reduction and cannot be discarded. This suggests that BW has trouble swapping pairs of arguments.

Comment: I don't expect it to be able to swap!

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, since I made a calculation mistake. Still just wanted to say that this is a nice question, which I don't know the answer to, and that the question of what we can get from just B and I (definitely not universal computation) was considered by Statman in [Combinators and the theory of partitions](https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/Combinators_and_the_theory_of_partitions/6477062/1).

Comment: @NoamZeilberger thanks! I missed the first comment :-) That reference looks interesting. I think I'd be quite happy if there was some kind of undecideability already in BW combinatory logic, even if not universal computation. But I may be misunderstanding what Statman is claiming

Comment: @DavidRoberts I ran a computation and was confused about how `(B(WW))((BW)((BB)B))` could give a fixed-point combinator, but I had a pair of misplaced parentheses. :-) In the paper I referenced about B+I, Statman proved that the *unification* problem is undecidable (given two B,I combinations with free variables, is there a substitution making them equal?).  However, the word problem can be solved in polynomial time by interpretation in $\lambda$-calculus, since every step of $\beta$-reduction reduces the size of the term. This is of course very different when you have $W = \lambda xy.(xy)y$.

Comment: @NoamZeilberger Ah, ok, so not quite so fancy. I could tell it wasn't much more serious undecideability, but wasn't sure how big the specified problem was. I myself also checked Statman's combinator when I learned of it, albeit by hand :-)